# IF else and for loop in one line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I need to apply if else condition and for loop in single line.I need to update both 'RL' and "RM" at a time and update other values as 'Others'.How to do it??.IS it possible??

```
train['MSZoning']=['RL' if x=='RL' else 'Others' for x in train['MSZoning']]
```

Comment: It's going to be a long line.

Comment: Better is avoid loops, `apply` are loops under the hood.

Comment: Thanks.It worked

Comment: @Anesh - Sure, both solutions works, but better is avoid loops, avoid `apply` because slow. Check it in my timings in edited answer.

Comment: Yes I saw it.Can you explain your code.What does  `isin` does??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
train['MSZoning'] = np.where(train['MSZoning'] == 'RM', 'RM', 'Others')
```

If need update all without `RM` and `RL` use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted boolean mask by `~`:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'MSZoning':['RL'] *3 + ['qa','RM','as']})
train.loc[~train['MSZoning'].isin(['RM','RL']), 'MSZoning'] =  'Others'

print (train)
  MSZoning
0       RL
1       RL
2       RL
3   Others
4       RM
5   Others
```

**Timings**:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'MSZoning':['RL'] *3 + ['qa','RM','as']})
#[60000 rows x 1 columns]
train = pd.concat([train] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [202]: %timeit train.loc[~train['MSZoning'].isin(['RM','RL']), 'MSZoning'] =  'Others'
5.82 ms ± 447 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [203]: %timeit train['MSZoning'] = train['MSZoning'].apply(lambda x: x if x in ('RM', 'RL') else 'Others')
15 ms ± 584 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to keep `RM` and `RL` while marking others as `Others` you can use:

```
train['MSZoning'] = train['MSZoning'].apply(lambda x: x if x in ('RM', 'RL') else 'Others')
```